# SWT: Problem with sashform children's width

Tags: java, swt

My application's got one horizontal SashForm with two children. The leftmost one should always be, at least, 200 pixels width. So I added a ControlListener to the left component. In its controlResized event I check the component's width. When it's smaller than 200, I set its bounds' width to 200. It apparently works as the component gets resized to that width, but the sashform stops working - the sash is no longer visible, it remains under the component.

Does anybody know what am I missing?

I've tried:

```
component.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
@Override
public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
if (component.getBounds().width < 200) {
Rectangle bounds = component.getBounds();
bounds.width = 200;
component.setBounds(bounds);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/eclipse/swt/examples/controlexample/SashTab.java.html) is an example

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the snippet! I looked at it and tried something similar to the resize() method on my code, setting the bounds for the sashform components and sash. Calling this method from an static event (e.g. pressing a button) works without problems, with the distances I set. But when resize() is called from the shell resize event, the effect is very different: components widths don't make any sense and the sash remains invisible. Did I miss something?

Comment: I have no test environment of my own. Justed pointed to an example that happened to treat the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but maybe you need to call pack() or layout() on the SashForm after you programatically resize the inner component.

Comment: Calling sashForm.layout() results in a "stack overflow" as that method involves launching again controlResized event - infinte recursion. pack() has no effect.